# Porting ServiceDescription code to .net Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, soap, .net-core

I have some .Net 4.8 C# code that reads in a WSDL from a SOAP Web service, and dynamically generates a UI for invoking methods provided by the service. I use the System.Web.Services classes such as ServiceDescription, MetadataSection, ServiceContractGenerator to do this. The code looks something like this:

```
System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescription serviceDescription
 = System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescription.Read(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(m_ServiceDescriptor)));
MetadataSection
 section =
MetadataSection.CreateFromServiceDescription(serviceDescription);
MetadataSet metaDocs = new MetadataSet(new MetadataSection[] {section});
WsdlImporter importer = new WsdlImporter(metaDocs);
ServiceContractGenerator serviceContractGenerator = new
ServiceContractGenerator(); ServiceEndpointCollection
serviceEndpointCollection = importer.ImportAllEndpoints();
```

I want to port this code to .Net Core 3.0, but cannot work out how to move the code that uses the System.Web.Services classes. As far as I can work out, System.Web.Services classes are not supported in .Net Core, but I can't find functional equivalent classes in the Microsoft.AspNet packages. So my questions are:

1. Is there some way to import the System.Web.Services classes into a
   .Net Core 3.0 application?
2. If not, where do I find the classes that
   do the same thing in .Net Core 3.0? Are they somewhere in the
   Microsoft.AspNet packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This scenario is not supported in .NET Core (I'm one of the developers on the WCF code base). The source is MIT licensed and available [here](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Description/ServiceDescription.cs) so you could try porting it yourself.

Comment: Hi - thanks for your response. I guess I'll try, but I'm not very familiar with building these libraries... So is it simply not going to be possible in .Net Core to dynamically consume and generate code for SOAP Web services? I was hoping that there'd be functionally equivalent classes in Microsoft.AspNet or some such library.

Comment: There are multiple technical barriers to porting runtime dynamic client generation. Basically it comes down most of the dependencies we use to achieve this on .NET Framework aren't there on .NET Core and while there are replacements for many of them, it's basically a re-write of that feature almost from scratch.